# Backend deployed faild on render

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, backend, render

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LynN4.png)

> I am using node.js for the backend and package  express cores mongoose on the MongoDB database
>
> I am getting this error when I am deploying my backend on the render

Answer (score 0):

Add a file called .node-version at the root of your repo containing a single line specifying the version.

Your .node-version should look something like this:

> 20.4.0

Please check suitable node version on local machine and then update it on above mentioned file - `.node-version` Use nvm to check and use different node compatibility. If this solution isn't working on your side, then check another alternative solutions on official website of  [Render.com](https://render.com/docs/node-version)